# Create a list from an existing list of key value pairs in python

Tags: python

I am trying to come up with a neat way of doing this in python.

I have a list of pairs of alphabets and numbers that look like this :

```
[(a,1),(a,2),(a,3),(b,10),(b,100),(c,99),(d,-1),(d,-2)]
```

What I want to do is to create a new list for each alphabet and append all the numerical values to it.

So, output should look like:

```
alist = [1,2,3]
blist = [10,100]
clist = [99]
dlist = [-1,-2]
```

Is there a neat way of doing this in Python?

Comment: you hear about defaultdict?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I didn't. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [('a',1),('a',2),('a',3),('b',10),('b',100),('c',99),('d',-1),('d',-2)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = defaultdict(list)

    for alphabet, number in data:
        result[alphabet].append(number)
```

or without collections module:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = {}
    for alphabet, number in data:
        if alphabet not in result:
            result[alphabet] = [number, ]
            continue
        result[alphabet].append(number)
```

But i think, that first solution more effective and clear.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without defaultdict too in case I don't want to use the collections library?

Comment: yes, of course you can do this without defaultdict, see edited answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using a `defaultdict` but are comfortable using `itertools`, you can do it with a one-liner

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [('a',1),('a',2),('a',3),('b',10),('b',100),('c',99),('d',-1),('d',-2)]
grouped = dict((key, list(pair[1] for pair in values)) for (key, values) in groupby(data, lambda pair: pair[0]))
# gives {'b': [10, 100], 'a': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [99], 'd': [-1, -2]}
```

Comment: I actually implemented my own dictionary. But thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the responses in the thread and reading the implementation of defaultdict, I implemented my own version of it since I didn't want to use the collections library.

```
    mydict = {}
    for alphabet, value in data:
        try:
            mydict[alphabet].append(value)
        except KeyError:
            mydict[alphabet] = []
            mydict[alphabet].append(value)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `defaultdict` from the `collections` module for this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [('a',1),('a',2),('a',3),('b',10),('b',100),('c',99),('d',-1),('d',-2)]
d = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in l:
    d[k].append(v)

for k,v in d.items():
    exec(k + "list=" + str(v))
```